# Where is the location of packages cached by apt-cacher?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, apt-cacher

When you install something by `sudo apt-get install <packageName>`, the packages are saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives` by default. I have installed and configured apt-cacher. I want to know where the packages cached by apt-cacher are stored? Are they saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`? If so how is it possible to change the cache directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default location where [`apt-cacher`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apt-cacher) stores its packages is `/var/cache/apt-cacher` .

If you want to change it, you need to run the `usr/share/apt-cacher/install.pl` script.

From [`man apt-cacher`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/apt-cacher.1.html)

```
 Universal Options
       cache_dir [/var/cache/apt-cacher]
              The directory where apt-cacher will store local  copies  of  all
              packages  requested.  This  can  grow to many hundreds of MB, so
              make sure it is on a partition with plenty of  room.  NOTE:  the
              cache directory needs to contain some subdirectories for correct
              storage management.  If you try to create  a  custom  directory,
              please  use  the  script /usr/share/apt-cacher/install.pl or use
              the initially created cache directory as example.
```